# Como funciona un "IF FOUND"

Tags: postgresql

tengo una inconveniente con un trigger, cada ves que actualizo el mismo dato ya creado me hace un nuevo registro, debes de actualizarme el registro ya dado,
la pregunta es , ¡como le digo que si el registro ya esta creado actualizarme o si no insertelo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usted puede uctilizar la cláusula ON CONFLICT en su INSERT. Con esto se puede dar UPDATE en algunas columnas somente, o no hacer nada.

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
 customer_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR UNIQUE,
 email VARCHAR NOT NULL,
 active bool NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE
);

INSERT INTO customers (NAME, email)
VALUES
 ('IBM', 'contact@ibm.com'),
 (
 'Microsoft',
 'contact@microsoft.com'
 ),
 (
 'Intel',
 'contact@intel.com'
 );

INSERT INTO customers (name, email)
VALUES
 (
 'Microsoft',
 'hotline@microsoft.com'
 ) 
ON CONFLICT (name) 
DO NOTHING;

INSERT INTO customers (name, email)
VALUES
 (
 'Microsoft',
 'hotline@microsoft.com'
 ) 
ON CONFLICT (name) 
DO
 UPDATE
   SET email = EXCLUDED.email || ';' || customers.email;
```

Comment: muchas gracias, pero no me funciono, me dieron la idea con "IF NOT FOUND"